# Why is this T-SQL duplicating results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why is this T-SQL duplicating results?

This query is fairly generic, so should replicate ok in any DB.

I get USPs duplicating in the TextLine column...

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name as TableName,  
        STUFF((
             SELECT ', ' + OBJECT_NAME(a.object_id)
             FROM sys.sql_dependencies a 
             WHERE a.referenced_major_id = b.object_id
             ORDER BY 1
             For XML PATH ('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS [TextLine]
FROM sys.sql_dependencies a JOIN sys.tables b ON a.referenced_major_id = b.object_id
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `DISTINCT` to the sub-query

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name                               AS TableName,
                Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Object_name(a.object_id) --Here
                       FROM   sys.sql_dependencies a
                       WHERE  a.referenced_major_id = b.object_id
                       ORDER  BY 1
                       FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS [TextLine]
FROM   sys.sql_dependencies a
       JOIN sys.tables b
         ON a.referenced_major_id = b.object_id
ORDER  BY TableName ASC
```

Now for each `table` only `distinct` depend `objects` will be concatenated

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Prdp :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is overly complicated.  You don't need a `join` in the outer query, and probably not the `select distinct` there either:

```
SELECT t.name as TableName,
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Object_name(d.object_id) --Here
              FROM   sys.sql_dependencies d
              WHERE  d.referenced_major_id = t.object_id
              ORDER  BY 1
              FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') AS [TextLine]
FROM sys.tables t
ORDER BY TableName ASC;
```

Actually, removing the outer `JOIN` probably removes the duplicates in the inner query as well:

```
SELECT t.name as TableName,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Object_name(d.object_id) --Here
              FROM   sys.sql_dependencies d
              WHERE  d.referenced_major_id = t.object_id
              ORDER  BY 1
              FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') AS [TextLine]
FROM sys.tables t
ORDER BY TableName ASC;
```